# Can i have alternative plugin instead of theme's default plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have purchased a **themeforest theme** for my **wordpress** site.
It requires 2 plugins : **Resolution Slider** and **Visual Composer**

[image]

Since these are paid plugins I want to use an alternative free plugins : **LenSlider** and **WP SiteBuilder** respectively.

Can I replace the plugins... If yes how? 
Also is **LenSlider the correct alternative for Slider Revolution**?

Comment: I also don't know why i can't add the wordpress-plugin tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only plugins supported by the theme can be used. However, plugin copies are free and updates may require you to pay some amount to use.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to use these plugins are they are supported with this theme. The copy of these plugins are free for you, if you get it with the theme. Updates to these may be required purchase version. If you use WP SiteBuilder instead of VC, it won't work. The slider may work.